# Ошибка при создании vue проекта

Tags: javascript, vue.js, установка, vue3, vue-cli

Установил vue

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но при создании проекта выдает ошибку

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите как ее устранить.

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался, см. [Ошибка «Невозможно загрузить файл ….ps1, так как выполнение сценариев отключено в этой системе» (РЕШЕНО)](https://zawindows.ru/%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7/).

Необходимо выполнить команду

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy unrestricted
```

в терминале PowerShell, зайдя в него от администратора.

Comment: [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)